# SSIS DataSource Component ignoring errors

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package that has say 4 datasources that all come together with a union all.

Now currently if one of them fails the whole package fails. Is there a way that i can make the package just go on if one or even more than one fails.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore failure or redirect rows in the source component through the error output tab.